TinyMCE Editor table border issue - 4.8.1 version
Borders are missing for rows, columns for a table in TinyMCE Editor.
I'm using TinyMCE Editor 4.8.1 in an Optimizely solution, and I've included the table plugin in the editor. However, when I select a specific number of rows and columns to create a table in the editor, the table doesn't display the gridlines for the user.
I've added the table plugin to the TinyMCE configuration in IServiceCollection.
services.Configure<TinyMceConfiguration>(config =>{
     config.Default()
    .AddEpiserverSupport()
    .EnableImageTools()
    .Menubar("edit insert view format")
    .AddPlugin("epi-link").AddPlugin("epi-image-editor").AddPlugin("epi-dnd-processor")
    .AddPlugin("epi-personalized-content").AddPlugin("print").AddPlugin("preview").AddPlugin("searchreplace")
          .AddPlugin("autolink").AddPlugin("directionality").AddPlugin("visualblocks").AddPlugin("visualchars")
    .AddPlugin("fullscreen").AddPlugin("image").AddPlugin("link").AddPlugin("media").AddPlugin("table")
    .Toolbar("formatselect | numlist  bullist | outdent indent | alignleft aligncenter alignright  |  epi-personalized-content | code | ")
    .BlockFormats("Paragraph=p;Header 1=h1;Header 2=h2;Header 3=h3; Header 4=h4;Header 5=h5;Header 6=h6");
 });

I've tried adding importcss plugin and content css plugin. but none of them worked.
When user see a table with data , it should have all the grids as designed in the editor.

You can customize the appearance of content inside the TinyMCE editor through a custom CSS:
services.Configure<TinyMceConfiguration>(config => {
   config.Default()
         .ContentCss("/static/css/editor.css") // Add preferred table styling to this CSS
});


Thanks Ted for the response. Do we have any plugin for css?

It's a standard CSS file for styling content inside the editor, i.e. inside the CMS only.
